# I want to make 3*3 Matrix format list in python

Tags: python

I want to make 3*3 Matrix format list in python , but when i try to print my list it printed the list items in single line . i do not avail to create newline between the every pass of the loop .

```
magic= [[ 0 for i in range (3)] for j in range (3)]
print(magic,'\n')
print()
```

**Original code:-**

```
magic= [[ 0 for i in range (3)] for j in range (3)]
print(magic)
```

Output:-

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Output that I want:-

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Comment: Do you want your data to format itself like this, or do you want some separate function that formats your data like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
def zeromat(n, p):
    return [[0] * p for i in range(n)]

def printmat(a):
    for v in a:
        print(" ".join(str(x) for x in v))

printmat(zeromat(3, 6))

0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you want your columns to be aligned, you will likely need a format when printing:

```
def printmat(a, fmt="%12.2f"):
    for v in a:
        print(" ".join(str(fmt % x) for x in v))


printmat([[10**i * j for j in range(3)] for i in range(6)])

    0.00         1.00         2.00
    0.00        10.00        20.00
    0.00       100.00       200.00
    0.00      1000.00      2000.00
    0.00     10000.00     20000.00
    0.00    100000.00    200000.00
```

Comment: Excellent example! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can join the inner list and print it in a separate line.

Code:

```
magic = [[ 0 for i in range (3)] for j in range (3)]
for line in magic:
    print(" ".join(map(str, line)))
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop to loop through the list and print the entries:

```
for i in magic:
        print(" ".join([str(_) for _ in i]))
```

Output:

> ```
> 0 0 0
> 0 0 0
> 0 0 0
> ```

**Or:**

```
for i in magic:print(i)
```

Output:

> ```
> [0, 0, 0]
> [0, 0, 0]
> [0, 0, 0]
> ```

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of the second example? Cheers! :)

Comment: @arsho The indentation is correct. I added raw codes

Answer (score 0):

Using `sep` argument of `print`:

```
for _ in range(3):
    print(*(0 for _ in range(3)), sep=' ')

# 0 0 0
# 0 0 0
# 0 0 0
```

Comment: What if all the values are not 0? This only works with OP example

Comment: @BlackThunder, all the values are 0 or any other number as per OP's question and example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
import numpy as np

# if you want another way to get your  3x3 matrix
magic = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=int).tolist()
print('\n'.join(' '.join([str(e) for e in l]) for l in magic))
```

output:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use multi dimensional list.

matrix = [ ]

for i in range(3): # since you only need 3 lists
    matrix.append([0, 0, 0]

print(matrix)